# Cython Pass String To C as Bytes

Tags: python, c, cython

I need to build a string in python and pass it to the wrapped C lib.  The C lib defines the function:

```
unsigned char load(char const *FileName)
```

In the .pyx file:

```
def test():
    PATH = '/usr/lib/libnx.so'
    PATH = <char*>PATH
    load(PATH)
```

But I get: `TypeError: expected bytes, str found`

I have tried encoding the python string but get the same error.

Comment: .encode() should fix that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, `str` objects are not byte arrays as in C. To get that, you must encode the string. The default is UTF-8 encoding, which is backwards compatible with ASCII.

Here are two ways to pass the array of bytes:

- Option 1: Define `PATH` to be a `bytes` object from the get-go:

  - `PATH = b'/usr/lib/libnx.so'`, or:
  - `PATH = 'usr/lib/libnx.so'.encode()`
- Option 2: Encode `PATH` into a byte array when you pass it:

  - `load(PATH.encode())`

Comment: Weird, I cannot replicate. Are you maybe forgetting to rebuild? I used `cpython` and imported the `stdlib::atoi()` which also takes a `char const *` at an argument. When I passed a `str` object it failed (like yours) but after using `.encode()` it worked.